# My program isnt adding a record to a table in a database

Tags: delphi

```
  var
    sName, sSurname, sUsername, sPassword, sPassword2: string;
begin
  sName:=edtName.Text;
  sSurname:=edtSurname.Text;
  sUsername:=edtUsername.Text;
  sPassword:=edtPassword.Text;
  sPassword2:=edtPassword2.Text;
  if sPassword=sPassword2 then
    with DataModule1 do
     begin
       tblLogInInfo.Open;
       tblLogInInfo.Last;
       while NOT tblLogInInfo.Eof do
         begin
           tblLogIniNfo.Insert;
           tblLogInInfo.FieldByName('Name').Value:=sName;
           tblLogInInfo.FieldByName('Surname').Value:=sSurname;
           tblLogInInfo.FieldByName('Username').Value:=sUsername;
           tblLogInInfo.FieldByName('Password').Value:=sPassword;
           tblLogInInfo.Post;
         end;
       ShowMessage('You have successfully created an account!');
       Form2.Close;
       Form1.Show;
     end
  else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Your passwords did not match. Please try again.');
    end;
```

This is the code I use to add a record, but it doesn't add the record. I've tried various other methods but it doesn't work.

I'm at the point where I'd like to restart the entire program, and I wouldn't like to do that due to the fact that I already have over 1,000 lines of code.

Comment: There's no need to move to the last record, either. 'Append' is supposed to add the new tuple to the end of the table, not that the physical position of the tuple is important. Is 'Name' the primary key of the table?

Comment: Nope. Its the ID field in the table which is an AutoNumber data type

Answer (score 2):

You are moving to the last record then doing a `while not EOF`. That is creating an infinite loop that would create the same record for ever.  Remove the WHILE and change the Insert to an Append.  Also, doing things this way is fine, but if you are using an SQL database that supports stored procedures you should look into using a stored procedure to do the insert instead.